# How to add Lptmr ISR to Interrupt Vector Table for Freescale K60DN board, ARM Cortex M4 Processor

Tags: arm, timer, interrupts, cortex-m4

I am attempting to use the low power timer of the Freescale K60 board. I have an interrupt handler written, and now do not know how to add the address of the handler to the interrupt vector table defined in startup_MK60DN.s.

Forgive me, I am struggling to fully understand interrupts

Comment: This question might help a little. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14705/how-are-interrupt-handlers-implemented-in-cmsis-of-cortex-m0 I suspect the interrupt is already declared in the table, you just need to define it with the right name.

Comment: So I have enabled the NVIC with the IRQ number for the lptmr. The question above does not address how externally defined isr's are supposed to be connected to the vector table. My issue is that I don't know how to link my isr with the nvic.

Comment: The startup file provides weak declarations of the functions. If you declare a function with the same name, the linker should give your version preference. You can check this by looking at the vector table in your final image. Search the example code you have for some other exception handlers, that ought to make it clear. You could add the toolchain details you are using - shouldn't make much difference but it might help someone gove you a more definitive answer.

Comment: https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Core/html/_using__c_m_s_i_s.html looks like the example you need.